# Validating Forward Slash

Tags: java

I am in an intro to Java class and we have to make a numerology program. i have everything except the data validation done. We have to validate that the date put in was put correctly, including the forward slash. I tried using

```
    if(slash1 !< /)
    continue;
```

as it is in a while statement to make the whole thing repeat if something is incorrect. It always tells me that using a forward slash is invalid. Could someone point me in the direction of how to solve this?

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your code? - it isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. Also `!<` is not a valid operator in Java, only `!=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little difficult to help until you post a bit more code and example data - what you have posted isn't valid Java...

You have `!<`, which is not a valid operator in Java, only `!=`.

You also have a plain `/` in the code, which is not legal Java - you'd have to quote it `"/"` or `'/'` to make it a legal `String` or `char` literal.

If you want to compare something against a String such as "/", you need to use `.equals()` or `.contains()` or similar methods. Do not try to compare Strings using `==` or `!=` or you will get [confusing results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

A powerful way to validate string patterns is to use Regular Expressions - see the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) on this topic.

Another way (for dates) is to define a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for your desired pattern.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did intend to type " != ". You answered my question. I just needed to make the / into a legal char. I would have copied my entire code over but unfortunately my school has copying to and from my Java program locked.